# error: org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: Undefined name 'data'. data is List (while debugging)

Tags: json, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

error: org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: Undefined name 'data'.

'data' is a List while debugging. The path is correct.

This is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class SharedPref extends StatefulWidget {
  const SharedPref({super.key});

  @override
  State<SharedPref> createState() => _SharedPrefState();
}

class _SharedPrefState extends State<SharedPref> {
  void readCountryCode() async {
    var data =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/local_files/country_code.json');
    print(data);
    print('object');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to read data from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Async operations are not immediately completed. While you are awaiting data, the following lines are executed. Therefore, data is undefined. Async computations don't block your code execution.

Please try the following:

```
Future<List> readCountryCode() async {
    var data =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/local_files/country_code.json');
    return data;
  }

print(readCountryCode());
```

I've given the future return type as List as you mentioned.

FYR - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html

Hope this helps!